# How to implement endless list?

Tags: android, memory-management

I have more than 10 million records in server and I want to fetch those data to my android device.

I have *implemented pagination* in list view, after page load I am adding newly loaded page to my array.

My question is **will I get out of memory exception** If I load all those pages?

If yes then **is there any efficient way to load millions of data?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes looks this is like a too big data structure. Memory exception is likely to appear, but there is no guarantee about this, it depends on the memory pressure.

The way to manage this is to only have a portion of your data at a given time: data present onscreen and some more to let user scroll up or down. When scrolling, application then fetches new data from the server and flush some older from the memory to control the space size.

Comment: looks nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ListView use [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which always gets recycle and you will never face issue related memory.